# Salesforce DX User restrict Production permisison on objects/Apps

Tags: user, salesforcedx

My requirement : 
I want DX User to be able to access only Dev-Hub/Scratch Org and Name Space registry. On the Dev-Hub, this user should NOT have ability to create records on any standard/custom object. If DX user uses Standard User profile, the user will still be able to create Standard Object records which I do not want.

I can achieve this my creating a new profile directly in production org restricting access to standard objects. But I wanted to do it through Meta-data deployment that goes through CICD pipeline. Since Dev-Hub is not present in lower environment sand boxes, I may not be able to do it through metadata deployment.

Can someone help me to achieve the functionality in first paragraph in a better way?

Comment: Just curious what you mean by "Dev Hub is not present in lower environment sandboxes".

Comment: Salesforce DX dev-Hub is only available in salesforce production org.

Comment: There's really no reason for dev hub to exist in a sandbox. Sandboxes are one of the "managed" org environments. Dev hub is the thing that "manages" your org environments. This seems to be a common misconception: what is the purpose of the dev hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a custom profile either way, so you may as well create your custom DX-only profile and leave it in production. The only alternative is to have a null profile (a profile with no object/field permissions) and then create a custom Permission Set, but that's only shifting the permissions from one undeployable object to another. DX development can't include Dev Hub permissions, because it's not possible to replicate a Dev Hub org in scratch orgs, developer orgs, or sandboxes, and so must exist outside of CICD.